# Why do I get console output from ACPID when devtmpfs is mounted and logged when not?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

I have a weird issue which I diagnosed all the way back to simply being that if I mount `devtmpfs` then launch ACPID daemon, i get console output, if I don't mount `devtmpfs`, the ACPI daemon output goes to the log.   I also get some `rpcbind` messages when `reboot` is issued, but I think it's the same thing (normally logs instead of output to screen).

```
apcid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
apcid: 1 rule loaded
apcid: waiting for events: event logging is off
```

Does anyone have any ideas why?  I can still use `udev` to create and load all my devices either way (mounting devtmpfs or not).  I tried setting up /etc/sysctl.conf to use kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3 (the default without it was 3 4 1 7), but that made no difference.

TIA

Comment: Seen tons of linux stuff on here, stack exchange doesn't have much.  What this site should do is do an interface to mailing lists so it can be used as forums for the mailing list.  Then official support lists would be available via a better format.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the mailing list suggestion. But if you think it is a viable idea, then you may want to (1) explain the problem (off-topic posts by new users?) and (2) suggest a fix (mailing lists?) at [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Meta is where issues are discussed (but rarely fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I had to restart syslogd and klogd after mounting `devtmpfs`.  Output to syslog that failed when to console due to apcid using LOG_CONS option.  This was busybox, `kill` and trying to start again didn't work, start-stop-daemon worked.